# Open CV, C++: "Error: The application was unable to start correctly (0x0000005)."

Tags: c++, opencv

I started working on OpenCV recently and configured OpenCV and MingW. I'm using Windows 7 OS. I am not using any IDEs for my programs. But still I am comfortable with the way I am doing the programs for now.

I wrote my first program and it compiled successfully but when I ran the `.exe` file it gave an Application error as :
`The application was unable to start correctly (0x0000005). Click OK to close the application.`

The following is the code I wrote:

```
#include "cstdlib"
#include "iostream"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std; 

using namespace cv;

int main() 
{

    Mat img = imread("v.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
    if (img.empty()) 
    {
        cout << "Error: Image cannot be loaded...!!" << endl;
        system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("MyWindow", img); 
    waitKey(0); 
    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); 

    return 0;
}
```

And for execution, I wrote a batch file as follows and executed it::

```
g++ -I"D:\opencv\opencv\build\include" -L"D:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" ImageTest1.cpp -lopencv_core246 -lopencv_highgui246 -o ImageTest1.exe
ImageTest1.exe 
pause
```

I also have added the following to the system path::

```
D:\MingW\bin;;D:\MingW\msys\1.0\bin;;D:\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\mingw\bin;;
```

I tried changing the x64 to x86. But that didn't work.

*Edit:* I executed the `.exe` as admin and it says `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application`

Comment: Don't you have to call some kind of init function first?

Comment: What's the output of the compilation step (the call to `g++`) ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that you have reported the error code accurately. I do not believe that the error code contains only 7 hex digits. It contains 8. I believe that you have missed off the first digit, which I bet is `c`. In which case the error message really is:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005).
```

Now, that code is the NT status code `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`. When the system tells you that *the application was unable to start* this means that the error is happening during the loader's code. In other words, your code has not even started running yet. The error will be occurring in the `DllMain` function of one of your dependent DLLs.

Most likely there is some incompatibility between the different DLLs that are being loaded. In order to debug this further you'll probably need to debug the loading process. Start by running Dependency Walker in profile mode to find out which module's `DllMain` is raising the exception. Hopefully Dependency Walker will be able to point you towards the mismatch that exists in your dependent libraries.

Comment: my OS is windows 7 64-bit. but the DLLs I've linked are for 32-bit. when I tried with 64-bit DLLs, it got errors saying 'undefined reference'

Comment: For a start can you confirm that the error code is what I believe it to be. And then edit the question. It does not matter one jot what your OS is. If the process is 32 bit, you use 32 bit DLLs. If the process is 64 bit use 64 bit DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

Put system imports in `<>` brackets. This is for `<cstdio>` and `<iostream>`.

EDIT: I misread the error code. Please ignore the rest of my answer.

<strike>It seems windows cannot locate the libraries on startup.</strike>

My assumption is based on the `0x7B` error.

Comment: What you say in paragraph 1 may be true, but the include files are processed at compile time and not at load time. And why does `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT == 0xc000007b` back up what you say?

Comment: Oh... I missed the `c` at the start... I thought the error was `0x0000007b == ERROR_INVALID_NAME`